# Question related to monotonicity of a function

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

**Question:**

> Let $S$ be the non-empty set containing all '$a$' for which $f(x)=\frac{4a-7}{3}x^3+(a-3)x^2+x+5$ is monotonic for all $x\in \mathbb R$. Find $S$.
>
> > Answer: $a \in [2,8]$

**My try:**

As $S$ contains all $a$,

$\implies$ all values of $a$ will constitute $S$.

As the given function is monotonous,

$\implies$ it will be either increasing or decreasing.

$\therefore f'(x)$ will be either $\ge$ or $\le$ to $0$.

If we take $f'(x)\ge0$, then on simplifying, we get $a\ge \frac{7x^2+6x-1}{4x^2+2x}$.

On differentiating $\frac{7x^2+6x-1}{4x^2+2x}$ and putting it equal to $0$, I got $x=1,-1/5$.

This gives the value of $\frac{7x^2+6x-1}{4x^2+2x}$ to be $2,8$ respectively.

I don't know how to go any further.

Comment: For a cubic $f$, if $f'(x_1)=f'(x_2)=0$ with $x_1<x_2$  then the quadratic $f'(x)$ is positive for $x<x_1$ and negative for $x_1<x<x_2,$ OR $f'(x)$ is negative for $x<x_1$ and positive for $x_1<x<x_2,$ and in either case $f $ is not monotonic.  If $f'(x)=0$ has at most $1$ solution then $f'$ cannot take both negative and positive values (as it is a quadratic), so $f$ is monotonic. And $f'(x)=0$ has at most one solution iff its discriminant is $\leq 0.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f'(x)=(4a-7)x^2+2(a-3)x+1$$

Once we must have $f'(x) \ge 0$ or $f'(x) \le 0$ for all $x$, and knowing that it is a quadratic function then we should have $\Delta \le 0$:

$$\Delta = 4(a-3)^2-4(4a-7) \le0 \Rightarrow a^2-10a+16 \le 0$$

that give us $a \in [2,8]$.

Comment: Oh.. How can I forget that. Btw there is a typo at the end. It should be a instead of x. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Doesn't the value of $f(x)$ depend upon the value of $a$ where $a$ is the coefficient of $x^2$ in the quadratic function. Like, when $a>0$ then, $f(x)\ge 0$ for $D \le 0$ where $D$ is the discriminant and when $a<0$ then, $f(x)\le 0$ for $D \le 0$.

Comment: I did't get it! Do you have any doubt?

Comment: Why will $D \le 0$ for $f'(x) \le 0$?

Comment: because $f'$ is a quadratic function and we want it to be, for example, always negative (in the decreasing case). In order to get that we need $\Delta \le 0$ because if not, $f'$ will have a piece negative an another positive.

Comment: Ok.. so does this mean that if $D$ is not less than $0$, then this curve will have some part above x-axis and some below and to make it completely below x axis, we take $D \le 0$?

Comment: @Cheapstrike: That is right!